# The package I created does not show up in Projects Window

Tags: android, android-studio

I made a package inside `com.example.asus.goldenestate`, But when finished making it, the package is not visible. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: restart your Studio, or check under project, it will be there.

Comment: @Sanoop i have restart my studio but nothing happend:(

Comment: is there any file inside the newly created package?

Comment: @Sanoop the folder is empty

Comment: Check the project location in the physical location of your HDD, and check if it exists

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalid and Restart, if nothing worked, create a file in the main package, and go to project folder location, and create new folder and move the file to the package and restart your Android Studio

Comment: @Sanoop The package I created is not on the HDD. When I create a package with the same name, the studio says the package already exists

Comment: Well thats strange, Are you extra sure that the package is not in the project location, anywhere?

Comment: @Sanoop yes i sure:( Maybe my way is wrong. How to add package in package?

Comment: Just as i told, create package in the physical location and add a temporary file, and then `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalid and Restart` and check if this works

Comment: @Sanoop Somehow now my problem is over. I've followed all your suggestions. I added a package with the same name, and now the package can be seen. Thanks for helping me. And sorry for my bad english.^^

Comment: Pheww.. Glad it somehow helped.. Always happy to help and no worries :) :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap on the small Gear icon on the top right-hand corner of the Project Window and make sure your settings are correct; Set your settings to match mine. (Red Arrow)

Make sure you are in `Android` mode from the drop down window on the left side (Purple Arrow)

Also, left click on the `Synchronize Icon` (CTRL+ALT+Y) on Windows which is located in the top left corner next to the save icon.

**NOTE:** If the above information did not help you, then hit `File` - `Invalidate Caches/Restart`. Wait for it to complete, and when it boots up Android Studio again watch the bottom right corner for all process to finish, then try again.

[image]

If all else fails, try to right click on the parent package `com.example.asus.goldenstate`, as seen in the new screenshot's Red Arrow. Give it a PROPER name (something simple like `mypackagetest`, then hit Add.

[image]

Comment: it's like that:(

Comment: @YulianaRahmahSolin Check my Update please, give that a shot.

Comment: I've done it, but the package I created is invisible too

Comment: Add the package again, I have a feeling the name you gave that package was invalid so no package was ever created in the first place. So, check my new updated answer. Create the package all over, and make sure you try with a simple name.

Comment: When I create a package with the same name, the studio says the package already exists. I added a package with the name "activity"

Comment: Somehow now my problem is over. I've followed all your suggestions. I added a package with the same name, and now the package can be seen. Thanks for helping me. And sorry for my bad english.^^

Comment: Your English is fine! :) Glad it's working, please accept the answer if you found that it helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Java Class in the new PAckage and check

Comment: How do I add java in an invisible packade?:(

Comment: File->New->Java Class

Comment: I want to add a java class into the package I created. But the package is not visible. :(

Answer (score 0):

There should be no check mark near the option "Compact Empty Middle Packages" in the Option Menu. [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECs4s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Other than these solution i suggest if nothing worked you can do it outside the Android Studio, Just replicate it in the physical location.

You can do by creating a package in the physical location adding a temporary file, and then `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalid and Restart`